# How to use setWorldOrigin with ARView?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

In the RealityKit code below I expect the box to be positioned lower given the world translation I've applied to y. I think I'm misunderstanding what setWorldOrigin does. I want to redefine the coordinate mapping so that zero is in a different location. What am I doing/expecting incorrectly? Thanks.

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero, cameraMode: .nonAR)
arView.environment.background = .color(.white)

var relativeTransform = matrix_identity_float4x4
relativeTransform.columns.3.y = -1
arView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: relativeTransform)
        
let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, isMetallic: false)
let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.3), materials: [material])
        
let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: .zero)
anchor.addChild(entity)
arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### AR solution

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244018/how-do-i-automatically-set-the-world-origin-to-a-new-point-on-the-floor-and-teth/76245217#76245217) for details.

---

#### Non-AR solution

ARSession is an AR object, so all session's properties and methods are working only when session is running. ARSession is meaningless in `.nonAR` mode (i.e. VR mode), on macOS app, and in the Xcode Simulator. In your case, I suggest using the following scenario.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class Camera: Entity, HasPerspectiveCamera, HasAnchoring {
    required init() {
        super.init()
   
        self.camera = PerspectiveCameraComponent(near: 0.01, 
                                                  far: 200.00, 
                                 fieldOfViewInDegrees: 50.0)
        self.transform.translation.y = 0.5
        self.transform.translation.z = 2.0
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        arView.environment.background = .color(.black)
        let camera = Camera()
        arView.scene.addAnchor(camera)

        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1))      
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: .zero)
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    }
}
```

#### P. S.

In RealityKit 2.0 using `.ar` mode, you can't change `far clipping plane` value.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Is there an equivalent way to set world transform when in .nonAR mode?

Comment: When working in VR, there is no scenario in which you need to move the coordinate grid. What for? `setWorldOrigin` is required in AR mode only, as the AR world origin, by default, is built at the same location where the ARCamera is.

Comment: I'm placing models within an empty space and redefining the origin down a few ticks means I don't have to keep adding an offset to coordinates. I understand that it is a small thing but if there was an easy way to move the origin why not do it?

Comment: Move cameras, move anchors, move models. What is the point of moving the coordinate grid in VR? In AR, this is necessary, in VR it's not necessary.