# How do you set the far clipping plane for RealityKit in AR mode?

Tags: ios, swift, realitykit

How do you access and modify the far clipping plane of the main camera in RealityKit while in AR mode? I am working in Swift.

Comment: Read this post, please – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71410039/how-to-use-setworldorigin-with-arview/71413998#71413998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RealityKit 2.0 it is not possible to set the far clipping plane.