# Why do I get a redundant Entity within the entity hierarchy after loading and anchoring a Model?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, arview

I have used the following code to

- `(1)` create an AnchorEntity and add to the ARView scene.
- `(2)` asynchronously load a model and tethered it to the AnchorEntity from (1).

The 3D model is from [here](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/models/tulip/flower_tulip.usdz).

```
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

let floorAnchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: [.horizontal],
                                         classification: [.floor],
                                         minimumBounds: [0.5, 0.5])
floorAnchorEntity.name = "floor anchor entity"
arView.scene.addAnchor(floorAnchorEntity)

cancellable = Entity.loadAsync(named: modelName)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
        switch loadCompletion {
            case .finished:
                print("model loading finished successfully")
            case let .failure(error):
                print("model loading failed due to \(error)")
            }
            cancellable?.cancel()
        }, receiveValue: { entity in
            floorAnchorEntity.addChild(entity)
        })
```

In the debugger, if I print out the entity hierarchy, I see a redundant entity named '/', which is not expected.

```
▿ 'floor anchor entity' : AnchorEntity, children: 1
  ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
  ⟐ AnchoringComponent
  ⟐ Transform
  ▿ '/' : Entity, children: 1
    ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ⟐ Transform
    ▿ 'flower_tulip' : Entity, children: 5
      ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
      ⟐ Transform
      ▿ 'TulipStalk' : ModelEntity
        ⟐ ModelComponent
        ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
        ⟐ Transform
      ▿ 'TulipPetals' : ModelEntity
        ⟐ ModelComponent
        ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
        ⟐ Transform
```

I was assuming that I'd have 'flower_tulip' directly under 'floor anchor entity'.

Am I missing something here or is this simply a bug?

P.S. a related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244018/how-do-i-automatically-set-the-world-origin-to-a-new-point-on-the-floor-and-teth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's an ordinary `.usdz`/`.reality` formats' scene hierarchy – some of scene's entities are groups, some of entities are models. So, all you have to do is just to [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150091/alternative-for-findentitynamed-method-to-find-a-specific-model-in-realitykit/76152401#76152401) this entity. Also note that if you need to get the model then you need to use [type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752649/realitykit-asynchronous-model-loading-doesnt-work).